# Increment value in cell according another value in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need do something in VBA but i don't know anything in it..

I don't find any code on the web doing what i need...

I've think this explain much what i need (this not work):

```
         Column A                  Column B
Rows 1 | N°                        | REFERENCE EXP
Rows 2 | 1                         | 305-871
Rows 3 | =if(B3<>B2;A3=A2+1;A3=A2) | 402-920
Rows 4 | =if(B4<>B3;A4=A3+1;A4=A3) | 402-920
Rows 5 | =if(B5<>B4;A5=A4+1;A5=A4) | 406-585
```

So, the result do something like that :

```
         Column A                  Column B
Rows 1 | N°                        | REFERENCE EXP
Rows 2 | 1                         | 305-871
Rows 3 | 2                         | 402-920
Rows 4 | 2                         | 402-920
Rows 5 | 3                         | 406-585
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might help you to improve your question.

Comment: I ment your vba code. What have you tried so far. If you don't know where to start. try recording a macro and then edit it to fit your liking.

Comment: You would need to add your values to a list, filter on unique values, and sort on A-Z (or whatever), then get an incremental value for them. Apply back to your original list the incremental value, where your values match. Seems quite easy, but you do have to give it a try yourself.

Comment: I find that : <br/>
`code`    Sub titi()
    Dim Lig As Long
    For Lig = 2 To Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Cells(Lig, 1).Value = Lig - 1
    Next Lig
    End Sub.`code` 
 
But that code count all rows. i need to count only if rows is not the same...

Answer (score 0):

I've find how to increment but the increment dosn't stop...

My code:

```
Set derlign = Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp)
'MsgBox ("Dernière ligne " & derlign & " !")
Set r1 = Range("A2:A100")
Set r2 = Range("B2:B100")
For N = 2 To r2.Rows.count
    If r2.Cells(N - 1, 1) = r2.Cells(N, 1) Then
       r1.Cells(N, 1) = r1.Cells(N - 1, 1)
    Else
       r1.Cells(N, 1) = r1.Cells(N - 1, 1) + 1
    End If
Next N
End Sub`
```

(my next post where i ask [how to stop the increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56288130/stop-increment-value-in-cell-according-another-value-in-another-cell))