# Stop increment value in cell according another value in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

According to [my precedent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56185236/increment-value-in-cell-according-another-value-in-another-cell)

I need to stop the increment, but I don't find out...

My code:

```
Range("A2").Value = "1"
Set derlign = Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp)
'MsgBox ("Dernière ligne " & derlign & " !")
Set r1 = Range("A2:A100")
Set r2 = Range("B2:B100")
For N = 2 To r2.Rows.count
    If r2.Cells(N - 1, 1) = r2.Cells(N, 1) Then
       r1.Cells(N, 1) = r1.Cells(N - 1, 1)
    Else
       r1.Cells(N, 1) = r1.Cells(N - 1, 1) + 1
    End If
Next N
End Sub`
```

but that give me :

```
N°  REF
1   305-77-871
2   402-88-920
2   402-88-920
3   406-55-585
3   406-55-585
3   406-55-585
4   404-11-885
4   404-11-885
4
4
4
...
```

Could you help me to stop the increment?

Answer (score 1):

Your increment stops automatically at `r2.Rows.count`, so you need to limit your range to the amount of data you have (instead of hard coding `100`).

If you tell VBA the range is up to `100` then of course the loop runs to `100`. Just use `derlign` to limit your range to the amount of data you have in column B.

```
    Set derlign = Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp)
    'MsgBox ("Dernière ligne " & derlign & " !")
    Set r1 = Range("A2:A" & derlign.Row)
    Set r2 = Range("B2:B" & derlign.Row)
    For N = 2 To r2.Rows.count
        If r2.Cells(N - 1, 1) = r2.Cells(N, 1) Then
           r1.Cells(N, 1) = r1.Cells(N - 1, 1)
        Else
           r1.Cells(N, 1) = r1.Cells(N - 1, 1) + 1
        End If
    Next N
End Sub
```

Actually I would change it to

```
Option Explicit

Sub WriteNumbering()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim RefData As Variant 'read REF into array
    RefData = ws.Range("B2:B" & LastRow).Value

    Dim NumData As Variant 'read Num into array
    NumData = ws.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value

    NumData(1, 1) = 1 'start number

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = LBound(RefData) + 1 To UBound(RefData) 'loop through array
        If RefData(iRow, 1) = RefData(iRow - 1, 1) Then
            NumData(iRow, 1) = NumData(iRow - 1, 1)
        Else
            NumData(iRow, 1) = NumData(iRow - 1, 1) + 1
        End If
    Next iRow

    'write the array back to the cells
    ws.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value = NumData
End Sub
```

Comment: `derlign` is a range, you will need to get it's row number.

Comment: @VincentG Good catch! Missed that … and fixed! Thanks.

Comment: Sorry... same result... and i forgot the first line : Range("A2").Value = "1"

Comment: @Ant00x see my edit. That should work. I tested it on your example data.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ : Thanks for your help but it doesn't work... I don't understand why ... if i add this line before end sub that give me 100 :     MsgBox ("Last line " & LastRow & " !") . But it's 41 in this case

Comment: @Ant00x That means you have more data in column B. That means in row 100 is data. Delete the data in B100.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ : I think i've found where does it come. I i've this line before : Range("X2:X100").Copy Range("B2:B100"). So, the B range is 1 to 100. I need to find how copy only X2 to last range of X2 in B column from B2 to n

Comment: @Ant00x This `ws.Range("X" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` will find the last used row in X. Use the last row as I did in the code above to get your range. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

To exit your loop early you can use the instruction 'Exit For'

```
If [condition] Then Exit For
```